# Как передать значение переменной из активности в класс в андроиде?

Tags: android

У меня есть активность и некоторый класс. Внутри активности я получаю значение сенсора смартфона, но я не знаю, как правильно передать это значение в класс для обработки. Устройство выдает исключение:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare().

Answer (score 0):

**************Activity ******************************

```
public class FtcRobotControllerActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
...

public static float currentDegree;
public float initialDegree = 0f;
...


@Override

  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    currentDegree = Math.round(event.values[0]);//update compass heading variable
    initialDegree = -currentDegree;
  }
```

*************** end of activity file **********************************

************* Compass_driver class ************************************

```
public class Compass_driver {
public static int getHeading(){
     return (int)com.qualcomm.ftcrobotcontroller.FtcRobotControllerActivity.currentDegree;
    }
}
```

************* end of Compass_driver class ******************************

---

```
public class ViewCompass extends OpMode {

 @Override
    public void init() {
    }
 @Override
    public void loop() {
      telemetry.addData("Compass value is ", Compass.getHeading());
    }
}
```

---

P.S. OpMode - класс для функционирования программы, именно этот класс исполняется смартфоном (т.е. роботом)

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил эту ошибку следующим образом

```
 if (Looper.myLooper() == null){
     Looper.prepare();
 }
```

[Мой похожий вопрос и решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829411/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-timer-%D0%B2-thread/829431#829431)