# Почему не работает Timer в Thread?

Tags: java, android

Реализовал отправку координатов пользователя на сервер, в UI потоке без TIMER код отрабатывает, теперь пытаюсь запускать поток раз в 5 секунд, ниже листинг

```
private void refreshUserCoordinates(final Context contextThread) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String user = intent.getStringExtra("user");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GeoPosition geoPosition = new GeoPosition();
            geoPosition.SetUpLocationListener(contextThread);
            ServerInteraction serverInteraction = new ServerInteraction("http://razdvatri/refreshCoordinates.php",
                    "{\"user\" " + ":\"" + user + "\", \"latitude\" " + ":\"" + geoPosition.getLatitude() + "\", \"longitude\" :" + "\"" + geoPosition.getLongitude() + "\"" + "}", "put");
            serverInteraction.execute();
        }
    }, 0L, 50L * 1000);
}
```

Вот что пишет LogCat

> 05-17 16:14:06.735 5372-5441/popovvad.findme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>       Process: popovvad.findme, PID: 5372
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>           at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:204)
>           at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:118)
>           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.(LocationManager.java:234)
>           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.(LocationManager.java:234)
>           at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:872)
>           at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:885)
>           at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:470)
>           at popovvad.findme.GeoPosition.SetUpLocationListener(GeoPosition.java:49)
>           at popovvad.findme.MapActivity$1.run(MapActivity.java:81)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) 05-17 16:14:30.306 5372-5372/popovvad.findme D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 05-17 16:14:30.307 5372-5372/popovvad.findme I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 5372 SIG: 9

Понимаю, что основная ошибка описана здесь -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

Как починить ?

Comment: Что если сделать так, как советует текст ошибки - вызвать `Looper.prepare()` первой строкой метода `run`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev перед первой строке в run написать Looper.prepare() или как поместить первую строку ? Можете написать как верно будет ?

Comment: Да я понятия не имею, как правильно будет. Просто `run() { Looper.prepare(); ... }` выглядит логичным вариантом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло в итоге в методе run() добавить

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == null){
     Looper.prepare();
 }
```

Полный листинг метода

```
private void refreshUserCoordinates(final Context contextThread) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String user = intent.getStringExtra("user");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            {
                Looper.prepare();
            }
            GeoPosition geoPosition = new GeoPosition();
            geoPosition.SetUpLocationListener(contextThread);
            ServerInteraction serverInteraction = new ServerInteraction("http://razdvatri.ru/refreshCoordinates.php",
                    "{\"user\" " + ":\"" + user + "\", \"latitude\" " + ":\"" + geoPosition.getLatitude() + "\", \"longitude\" :" + "\"" + geoPosition.getLongitude() + "\"" + "}", "put");
            serverInteraction.execute();
        }
    }, 0L, 50L * 1000);
}
```